# Excel if vaules of 2 columns match then take the difference of another two columns

Tags: excel-formula

I have 4 columns of data.  I want to match the values of two of the columns then if take the difference of two other columns if the first two match. So it's accounts and amounts.

Example. If col A matches Col C take the difference of Col B and Col D and Out it in Col E

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D   Col E  
1234    $100    1234    $100    $0  
1235    $120    1235    $150    $-30  
1236    $150    1237    $150  
1238    $130
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A1=B1,C1-D1,)
```

A1 and B1 are cell references to values you are comparing, and C1 and D1 are cell references to the values you are trying to take the difference of. If you'd like to have the cell be blank instead of 0, add "" after the last comma.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if your problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming first data row to be A2:E2, Please put below mentioned formula in cell E2

=IF(A2=C2,B2-D2)

Similarly you can do reverse action by like if it is not then add them or put 0  or blank by "" or subtract B2 from D2 by below given options.

=IF(A2=C2,B2-D2,B2+D2)

=IF(A2=C2,B2-D2,0)

=IF(A2=C2,B2-D2,"")

=IF(A2=C2,B2-D2,D2-B2)

Hope this would help!

Comment: Yes, this helps too.